# How to Populate Combo Box Access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, text, auto-populate

I am trying to fill in a combo box with names from a text file.  The file ill ready something to the affect of.

Greg Smith
John Oliver
Bob Cassidy
....
....

So far I have the code from another thread which works great but only takes the last name from the list and the other names are no where to be found.  The code is:

Dim MyStr1 as string
dim MyStr2 as string

Open "TESTFILE" For Input As #1
Do While Not EOF(1)    ' Loop until end of file.
    Input #1, MyStr1, MyStr2
    me.txtStr1 = MyStr1
    me.txtStr2 = MyStr2
Loop
Close #1    ' Close file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To be clear the names are on different lines.  Did not notice my error.

Comment: So [edit] your post and fix them. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're just trying to populate one combo box with a list of first and last names (where the names are separated by a line break), try this:

```
Dim filePath As String
Dim oFSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim oFS As TextStream

filePath = "C:\FileFullOfNames.txt"

Set oFS = oFSO.OpenTextFile(filePath)

Do While Not oFS.AtEndOfStream
  MyForm.ComboBox1.AddItem oFS.ReadLine
Loop

oFS.Close

Set oFS = Nothing
```

If you've never used FileSystemObject & TextStream, you'll need to add the Microsoft Scripting Runtime reference in your VBE.  (Tools > References > Check the box labeled "Microsoft Scripting Runtime").

Comment: Thank you for the help but I am getting error-code 91 when running the code.  Stating the my Object variable or with-block variable is not set.  The debugger points to the line "Set oFS=oFSO.OpenTextFile(filepath)"  I also added the library before running the script.

Comment: Sorry about that.. I had set oFSO to nothing without setting it to something in the first place.  Try the edit

Comment: Thank you so much, that did the trick.  Now I can finally finish this project. I don't think I can up vote your comment, being new to the website.  So i hope you accept my written thank you. @CharlieOscarDeltaEcho